# Cannot understand Algorithm's complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I am learning algorithms and stumbled upon this article in top coder.

This is an example from the [article](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=complexity2)

```
int result=0;                           //  1
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)                 //  2
  for (int j=i; j<N; j++) {             //  3
    for (int k=0; k<M; k++) {           //  4
      int x=0;                          //  5
      while (x<N) { result++; x+=3; }   //  6
    }                                   //  7
    for (int k=0; k<2*M; k++)           //  8
      if (k%7 == 4) result++;           //  9
  }                                     // 10
```

*The time complexity of the while-cycle in line 6 is clearly O(N) - it is executed no more than N/3  + 1 times.*

I am confused here as author says time complexity is O(N). For me it seems O(N^4). Please explain, what am I overlooking. I am only starting algorithms.

Comment: Just read the rest of the article.  When he says O(N), he's only talking about line 6 in isolation.  At the end he says that the total time complexity of the algorithm is O(MN^3).

Comment: "The time complexity **of the while-cycle in line 6** is clearly O(N) - it is executed no more than N/3 + 1 times."

Comment: @BilltheLizard beat me by seconds. If he posts it as an answer, I'll withdraw mine.

Comment: Now that's what happens when studying late. It's 0200hrs here (India) and I was staring at the monitor for like 20 mins without reading next few lines and got stumped. Thanks anyways guys. I should now go to sleep :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of **the while-cycle in line 6** is O(N).